# How do you derive the output impedance of this BJT stage?

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am given the following circuit (neglect Early effect):

[image]

And, I am asked to find the output impedance looking into where `V_out` is taken

By inspection, I can tell that the output impedance would be:

```
r_pi + R_c
```

But, I wish to apply a small `v_x` at the output node and compute `v_x/i_x`.

I arrive at the following circuit small signal model:

[image]

But, simplification of the KCL does not lead to `r_pi + R_c`.

So, is the small signal model correct? I would appreciate some clarification if my steps are wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Your inspecion is wrong. Also where is Q1 in your small signal circuit?

Comment: Since Early effect is neglected, I assume the Q1's `r_o` is infinite. And, it appears in parallel with Q2's `r_pi`. Therefore, I left it out of the model.

The textbook solutions states that `R_out = r_pi + R_c` . https://imgur.com/a/tLOvDNi

Comment: Sorry I misread. Vin is set to 0 so Q1 is not included. Let me check in a minute your result.

Comment: Your calculation looks correct. And the book seems wrong.

Comment: I would not be surprised. I've seen errors in the solutions before.

Comment: For this circuit the output impedance is $$R_{OUT} = \frac{r_\pi +R_C}{1 + g_m r_\pi}$$ or $$R_{OUT} =\frac{r_\pi +R_C}{\beta +1}$$

Comment: Thanks, I arrived at the same conclusion. As @anhnha has pointed out, my approach was correct and the book solutions were wrong. I just simplified my KCL equation and arrived at the same result as G36